# Toggle Effect is not working in plain HTML

Tags: jquery, html, twitter-bootstrap, twitter-bootstrap-3

The toggle effect is not working in the html code but the code works when I tried using jsfiddle. I couldn't understand why. Can someone help ?

```
<html>
 <head>
  <link href="http://netdna.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/3.0.3/css/bootstrap.min.css" rel="stylesheet" />
  <script src="http://netdna.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/3.1.1/js/bootstrap.min.js"></script>
  <script src="http://code.jquery.com/jquery-1.10.1.js"></script>

 </head>
<body>
<button type="button" class="btn btn-danger" data-toggle="collapse" data-target="#40763">Toggle Check</button>
   <p id="40763" class="collapse in">Vinoth</p>

</body>
```

The following fiddle link works perfectly [jsfiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/M48YE/)

I have tried add javascript and css at the bottom of body.

Comment: You should always check your console while debugging...

Answer (score 3, accepted):

`bootstrap.js` used jQuery, so change the include order of the script files.

```
<script src="http://code.jquery.com/jquery-1.10.1.js"></script>
<script src="http://netdna.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/3.1.1/js/bootstrap.min.js"></script>
```

Demo: [Problem](http://jsfiddle.net/arunpjohny/MDzSX/1/), [Solution](http://jsfiddle.net/arunpjohny/MDzSX/2/)

Comment: Thanks a lot:) It was the mistake.

Answer (score 0):

**bootstrap js** depends on **jQuery** so please change your order to include script

```
<link href="http://netdna.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/3.0.3/css/bootstrap.min.css" rel="stylesheet" />
    <script src="http://code.jquery.com/jquery-1.10.1.js"></script>
<script src="http://netdna.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/3.1.1/js/bootstrap.min.js"></script>
```